# One to One relationShip in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**Job Model**

```
class Job_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tbljobs";
    protected $primaryKey = "JobID";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function OrderType()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\OrderType_Model', "OrderTypeID");
    }
}
```

**Order Type Model**

```
class OrderType_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblOrderType";
    protected $primaryKey = "OrderTypeID";
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**Query**

```
$Jobs = \App\Models\Job_Model::with("OrderType")->get();
```

**I am retrieving all records from `tbljobs` table. but each record is not showing associated record from Order Type Table.**

> Am I missing something ?

**dd() result**

[image]

Comment: Can you dd() the results of that query and paste it here?

Comment: Can you `dd()` the result of `\App\Models\Job_Model::with("OrderType")->get()->toSql()`?

Comment: Is/are there any records in `OrderType_Model` ?

Comment: `orderTypeID` and `OrderTypeID` are 2 different strings for laravel

Comment: Try listening for the query event
`Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
{
 var_dump($query);
});`
And see if the query is correct. You can put it in the routes.php just for testing.

Comment: Use toSql() before you run get(). It has to be run on the query object and get() returns a collection of jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `has()` and `with()`. Has returns only jobs with order types and with actually injects the order type into each job.

```
 $Jobs = \App\Models\Job_Model::has("OrderType")->with("OrderType")->get();
```

Edit: if your foreign key is actually in the Jobs table, not the Order type table, you want a belongs to relationship.

`hasOne()` assumes the foreign key is in the other table.

`belongsTo()` assumes the foreign key is in this table.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your question is just how you could see dumped data on the screen? Try it like this

```
$Jobs = \App\Models\Job_Model::with("OrderType")->get();

foreach ($Jobs as $job) {
    var_dump($job->toArray());
}
```